# How can call textbox.text from dll by vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I made form and put textbox inside form1 and i have text in textbox after that I compile projact as dll

My problem how can call or get the text form dll 
Form another project

Comment: The fact that the form class is declared in the DLL is irrelevant.  The `TextBox` class itself is declared in a DLL too and yet you don't have trouble using that, do you?  You create an instance of this form in exactly the same way as you would any other form and you access data in that form object like you would any other.

Comment: I'm still new I don't know I need the code to can text from dll

Comment: So you know, you call methods (functions and subs in VB).  Objects are *referenced*.  If you want the text of a textbox, you arent calling anything, just referencing the control and accessing a property it has: `myText = Textbox15.Text`